# Git pull origin main gives error Aborting

Tags: git, github, django-admin, digital-ocean, droplet

I get this error when I try **git pull origin main**. It does not even says why it's aborting. I even tried git reset but giving same error. What should I do? Please help.

```
static/admin/js/vendor/select2/118n/fr.js 

static/admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/g1.js

static/admin/js/vendor/select2/118n/he.js 

static/admin/js/vendor/select2/118n/h1.js

static/admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/hr.js 

static/admin/js/vendor/select2/118n/hsb.js 

static/admin/js/vendor/select2/118n/id.js 

static/admin/js/vendor/select2/118n/ka.js 

static/admin/js/vendor/select2/118n/10.js static/admin/ js/vendor/select2/i18n/nb.js

static/admin/js/vendor/select2/118n/hu.js 

static/admin/Js/vendor/select2/i18n/hy. Is

static/admin/js/vendor/select2/118n/Is.js 

static/admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/it.js 

static/admin/js/vendor/select2/118n/Ja.js

static/admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/km.js 

static/admin/js/vendor/select2/118n/ko.js

static/admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/lv.js

static/admin/js/vendor/select2/118n/mk.js

static/admin/js/vendor/select2/118n/ms.js

Aborting
```

Comment: What does it show you when running with `-v`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My error got solved by using `git clean  -d  -f ""`, then `git stash` commands. Thank You.